# Valid t-test usage and findings?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

Thanks to @glen_b

I am comparing a low range variable's scores (0-4) at three time points - A, B, and C. The scores belong to one group of 102 participants. The three time point score distributions are non-normal.

I have used a paired samples t-test, but I have not adjusted for risk of Type I error, e.g. through the use of a procedure like Bonferroni.

My results were: A vs B t(102)=4.988 p=.000; A vs C t(102)=4.939 p=.000; B vs C t(102)=.346 p=.730.

I did not use the Bonferroni because I did not want a risk of Type II error, i.e. I wanted to increase the chances of finding significance through having a higher alpha level (i.e. .05). I also wanted to use a simple statistical procedure which immediately told me where the differences were.

One may argue I should have used a Bonferroni correction, however, if used, because there were three tests computed which gives a Type I error risk of 14.3% (at .05), the Bonferroni adjustment is .016. I am wondering if the Bonferroni correction argument is still valid given the p values are below the .016 regardless? Wouldn't that basically infer that it wouldn't matter if I did a Bonferroni or not, the t-test results of significance are valid.

Ideally (again thanks to Glen_b), a count-based statistic might have been used instead of t-test, due to the low range of scores. Are there any advantages to having used a t-test here?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what the problem is... if you've done a Bonferroni correction and you still have two significant results, then you have two significant results.  That's not a reason for not doing the Bonferroni correction, which is what your next-to-last paragraph implies you are thinking! 2. "I wanted to increase the chances of finding significance through having a higher alpha level"... this is dangerous, as you can always find significance by choosing a high enough alpha level.

Comment: You still appear to be mixing together distinct issues, asking about more than one of the issues that came up in the same question. Some of these have, IMO, already been dealt with in the answers to the previous question (indeed, it seems you were already aware in your earlier post that seeking to reduce type II error by avoiding correction might be problematic). I identified four distinct issues in the extensive comments under the earlier post. As far as possible please try to keep to one issue per post.